# Creating a remote controller for android

Tags: java, android, connection, communication, wmp

I am very new to the android community and do not really know how everything works.

I want to create my own very basic remote controller for my phone that I can use to control WMP on my server.  (play, volUP/volDOWN etc..)

I would believe that I need some kind of application that does some kind of communication bewteen my phone and WMP though...

Is this easy to create or do anyone know of a freeware application that I can use for the communication?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Gmote](http://www.gmote.org/).

It has full VLC support, and a Beta support for Windows Media Player. More info in this at the [Gmote FAQ Section](http://www.gmote.org/faq#Can_I_use_a_media_player_other).

You'll need to install the client on your mobile device, and a specific application on your server, both dowloadable for free from the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets to communicate between mobile and desktop. Java provides a class java.awt.Robot which you can use to simulate mouse and keyboard events.

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.mouseMove(x,y)
```

[Here](http://codesmith.in/control-pc-from-android-app-using-java/) is an article that tells how to communicate between PC and android app by creating a simple VLC remote control. You can extend the concept to create a remote control for WMP.